# How do I create individual XML files from the parsed data output of a XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I have written a program (DOM Parser) that parses data from a XMl File. I would like to create an individual file with the corresponding name for each set of data parsed from the xml document. If the parsed output is Single, Double, Triple, I would like to create an individual xml file (Single.xml, Double.xml, Triple.xml)with those corresponding names. How do I create the xml files and give each file the name of my parsed data output? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MyDomParser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  try {
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse("ENtemplate.xml");
  doc.normalize();

  NodeList rootNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("templates");
  Node rootNode = rootNodes.item(0);
  Element rootElement = (Element) rootNode;
  NodeList templateList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("template");

  for(int i=0; i < templateList.getLength(); i++) {
  Node theTemplate = templateList.item(i);
  Element templateElement = (Element) theTemplate;
  System.out.println("Template" + ": " +templateElement.getAttribute("name")+ ".xml");

  }
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SAXException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the File I/O APIs as usual to create your xml files within the loop.

```
// for every Node in the template List
for(int i=0; i < templateList.getLength(); i++) {

  // cast each Node to a template Element
  Node theTemplate = templateList.item(i);
  Element templateElement = (Element) theTemplate;

  // get the xml filename as = template's name attribute + .xml
  String fileName = templateElement.getAttribute("name") + ".xml";

  // create a Path that points to the current directory
  Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);

  // create the xml file at the specified Path
  Files.createFile(filePath);

  System.out.println("File "+ fileName + ".xml created");
}
```

The above code would create the xml files in your current working directory. You'll need to handle the checked `IOException` too.

Comment: @ravionline If possible can you please add comments to your code?